# How works Fargate with multiple autoscaling policies?

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-auto-scaling, cloudwatch-alarms

I'm wondering how a Fargate service prioritize the escalation policy when it have more than one.

**Assuming these two configurations:**

- The first one scale when the number of messages in SQS is over than 100
- The second one scale when the service CPU is over than 70%

**Scenery**

We have only one service in our ECS with launch type FARGATE. In the service we have running only 1 task that contains only one container that corresponds to the application.

Is triggered a cloudwatch alarm because the number of messages exceed 100 messages, so the autoscaling will be triggered too and add 1 task to the service. Right at that very moment, the CPU service increase because an external service is making a lot of requests in the API, so the autoscaling is triggered and add another task.

What happend if the number of messages is less than 100 but the CPU is still increasing? What about the tasks added by the policy that was triggered by SQS? It will remove the tasks no matter what? There is no logic behind where they complement each other or they works or do they work completely independent of each other??

Answer (score 0):

if the cpu is below 70%, new tasks added will be removed.

Documentation says [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/application/userguide/application-auto-scaling-target-tracking.html):

> We recommend caution, however, when using target tracking scaling policies with step scaling policies because conflicts between these policies can cause undesirable behavior. For example, if the step scaling policy initiates a scale-in activity before the target tracking policy is ready to scale in, the scale-in activity will not be blocked. After the scale-in activity completes, the target tracking policy could instruct the scalable target to scale out again.